# Nuclear pulsejet

Tags: mechanical-engineering, engines, nuclear-engineering, nuclear-technology, jet

As the title suggests, I am wondering about the feasibility of Nuclear powered pulsejet engines, including Radioisotope Thermoelectric Generators (RTGs). I am not talking about *Nuclear pulse* rockets, that use nuclear explosions to generate thrust, but *pulsejets*

Is it possible to build such engine? And if not, what would be the simplest atmospheric nuclear engine that can be feasibly built?

Comment: Given that you have very few constraints and no clear performance criteria, of course it is possible. Will you go build one now? Probably not.  Simplest atmospheric nuclear engine is a banana or piece of wood that I drop.  If it needs to generate thrust, from a nuclear reaction, then just let an uncontrolled reaction of that form loose.

Comment: You realize that an RTG has the specific power of a dead lead acid battery, right? If you don't need 10 years unrefueled, they aren't anything you want to hold in the air.

Answer (score 0):

Could you create a pulse jet that was powered from the heat of a decaying radioisotope?  Yes, it would be low-powered and expensive (and with all the difficulties of working with highly radioactive materials).  Pulsejets are already inefficient, starting with a very low power source would make it even more difficult.  I doubt you could get enough power from such a device to keep it aloft in the atmosphere.

Theoretically you could use the heat from such a decaying pellet to power a putt-putt boat, which is just a simple pulse jet.